# Loading html template using django fails

Tags: python, django

The following is my folder structure

```
  geoff
    settings.py
    urls.py  //using this
    wsgi.py

homepage
  migrations->folder
 _init_.py
 .....others here
 views.py
  index.html
```

In my geoff urls //root url

```
from homepage import views as homepage

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', homepage.home, name = 'homepage')
]
```

NOw the homepage views.py

```
def home(request):
  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
   context = RequestContext(request, {
    'latest_poll_list': "new",
   })
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The above throws an error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at 
homepage.html
```

What could be wrong?

UPDATE ON SETTINGS.PY

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig'
)

 TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

As from the above ive already included Homepage app in settings but still fails to work.

Comment: can you show your settings.py code

Comment: create a templates/ directory inside homepage, and put index.html in there

Comment: please show your template directory in your settings.py

Comment: @SPSP Ive added it

Comment: @Richard still it fails to work.

Comment: @c.grey ive updated the question with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TEMPLATES settings should be like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ####
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ####
   }
    ]
```

then your folder structure:

```
templates
    index.html
    ...other html
geoff
    settings.py
    urls.py  //using this
    wsgi.py

homepage
    migrations->folder
    _init_.py
    .....others here
    views.py
```